# Undefined reference to power

Tags: c

I get an `Undefined reference` error when trying to compile this code.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int power(int m, int n);

int main()
{
    printf("%d", power(2,5));
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You get this error when trying to *link* it. It will compile fine.

Answer (score 2):

You *declared* `power` but you need to *implement* it.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int power(int m, int n)
{
  .. your code goes here
}

int main()
{
    printf("%d", power(2,5));
    return 0;
}
```